# kafka cluter not all replication are coming as ISR

Tags: apache-kafka

We have multinode Kafka 1.0.1 cluster (tried earlier version also) and when we are creating this cluster we have given replication as n-1 so if 7 we have nodes we are giving 6 as replication factor but not all replicas are becoming ISR. This issue happens for some topics and for some it create. If we recreate multinode cluster 2-3 times it creates ISR for all replicas. Did someone got similar issue and help on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your replication factor seems to be quite high. Why do you set it to n-1? The replication factor should be independent from the cluster size. For most use cases a replication factor of 3 is sufficient. There are also use cases with stronger demands that use a replication factor of 5. I guess a higher replication factor would be very rare. If you don't have special needs, 3 should be sufficient.
2. The larger the replication factor, the more time it needs to replicate data -- thus, if you continuously write to the leader, the followers need some time to copy the data, and the network bandwidth to copy the data is obviously limited. Thus, with a larger replication factor, each individual follower has less bandwidth for copying the data and might fall back and thus never become an ISR.

Comment: Thanks , yes that is issue , we lower our replication and got issue resolved. also we change our instance type to have higher network bandwidth.